# pass parameter inside generateStaticParams function for SSG NextJS

Tags: next.js, i18next, static-site-generation, app-router

for my SSG page I need to pass a parameter which is language to my api call function which is inside `generateStaticParams` function, I have stored language inside cookies and I can not access that, is there a way I can pass params to my function?

```js
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const getAllCategories = await getCategories(); // this needs language
  return getAllCategories.map((category: Category) => ({
    id: category.id,
    category: category.groupName,
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies with Nextjs official lib in Next13

```
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';

export async function generateStaticParams() {

    const cookieStore = cookies();
    const language = cookieStore.get('language');

    const getAllCategories = await getCategories(language); // this needs language
    return getAllCategories.map((category: Category) => ({
        id: category.id,
        category: category.groupName,
    }));
}
```

Comment: getStaticProps is not available in Next13 app dir

Comment: Updated to `getServerSideProps`

Comment: also this is not available, refer do the docs functions section (with app router not pages)

Comment: Updated to Next13 using app router